# Game not recieving WM_KILLFOCUS message while in fullscreen

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I'm working on a game using DirectX and WinApi. While in windowed mode, everything works fine, either Alt+Tabing or clicking outside of a game window sends WM_KILLFOCUS message. But while in fullscreen, Alt+Tab does not send the said message.

Is this the matter of setting some parameters of D3D renderer? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I think that fullscreen DX applications simply do not have focus. Probably you can use WM_ACTIVATE instead.

Comment: I'm posting it as answer so you can accept it, if you feel like it ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that fullscreen DX applications simply do not have focus. Probably you can use [WM_ACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. It will get in `wParam` the values `WA_ACTIVE` or `WA_CLICKACTIVE` for activation, or `WM_INACTIVE` for deactivation.